# Use SOAP API to send report

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, reporting, soap

Is there a way to send reports to an e-mail address using the soap api? I would like to receive the "Recent E-mail Sending Summary" daily without having to manually send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the API to do this. You can easily create a **[Report Activity](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/report_activity/)** inside SFMC, add then add that to a **[Program](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/programs/)** or **[Automation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/automation_studio/)** to run it at an interval.

If for some reason using the API is a requirement of your project, you might be able to create the Report Activity and then perform it using the SOAP API as outlined **[here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/reportactivity/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i opted for the reported activity.